# When you create custom questions in bookings where can I find the answers through the API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In Microsoft bookings, I added some custom questions to ask the person filling out the form.

I have gone through all the APIs and I can't find the answers?

In the Web UI I go to my calendar, open the appointment, click on the customer name... I can see the answers to my questions.

Does anyone know if those as accessible through the API?

Thanks,
Terry

Comment: Can you explain in detail what you're trying to do?

Comment: Not sure I can explain more than I did above?  I'm trying to get answers to custom questions in bookings through API.  But I dont think Microsoft has exposed those.

Comment: Sis you ever solve this? I have the same issue.